# Locations where Blade components are being registered in Laravel

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8

So, I have inherited a Laravel 8 project from the previous developer who decided to leave for a greener pasture.  And I see all this blade components everywhere, (`x-this`, `x-that`) and I have also created a few.  I have used `make:component` command and I can see the components being generated both in `App/Views/' and 'resources/views'.  That's great.

Now, there are other components, which the previous developer have created that I can't figure out where where these components are being registered at.  They are not in the App directory, not in the service provider boot, there's no custom vendor in the composer.

So, I think the obvious question is, where else should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

Those may be anonymous components. Anonymous components does not require any registration. So check resources/views/components folder.

For more info:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#anonymous-components